# R Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U", none of the usual solutions work

Tags: r

One of my students is encountering this problem in R, while using `read.csv()`. He uses windows, with which I'm rather unfamiliar, since I use Linux. 
We tried all the usual solutions: manually converting the backslash to forward slash, double backslash, removing the `/C:`, and putting `file=` in front of the path string and all sensible combinations of those. Nothing works and he keeps getting this error. Has anybody of you encountered this problem before and found a solution? I couldn't find any more suggestions than what we tried already...
Thanks so much! The code we tried was:

```
results= read.csv("C:/User/desktop/file.txt")
results= read.csv("/User/desktop/file.txt")
results= read.csv("C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt")
results= read.csv("\\User\\desktop\\file.txt")
results= read.csv(file= "C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt")
results= read.csv(file= "C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt")
results= read.csv(file= "\\User/desktop/file.txt")
results= read.csv(file= "C:/User/desktop/file.txt")

results= read.csv('C:/User/desktop/file.txt')
results= read.csv('/User/desktop/file.txt')
results= read.csv('C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt')
results= read.csv('\\User\\desktop\\file.txt')
results= read.csv(file= 'C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt')
results= read.csv(file= 'C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt')
results= read.csv(file= '/User/desktop/file.txt')
results= read.csv(file= 'C:/User/desktop/file.txt')
```

And the same combinations with `read.table()` instead of `read.csv()`. 
None of it works.

Comment: All backslashes need to be escaped in the file path (or replaced with forward slashes).  This is going to be user error but without seeing the actual command causing the error nobody can say what the problem is.

Comment: We already tried replacing the backslashes or escaping them. It didn't work. That's why I'm asking here. All the solutions that were posted before do not work and produce the same error again.

Comment: I understand that but it wasn't clear from your post if you amended the backslash you thought was causing a problem or *all* backslashes.  But my point stands, without seeing the code being used it's really difficult to offer further advice.

Comment: I adedd most of the code we tried. Neither of it worked. I've never encountered this problem before, but I'm also working on Linux so I never ahve the problem with backslashes...

Comment: Don't put any slashes in front of "C" - just "C:\\User\\desktop\\file.txt"

Comment: My bad, sorry. We didn't put slashes before C. I'll change it in the post.

Comment: Try using RStudio and the "Import Dataset" -> "From Text (base)" option? (In the Environment pane.) Let RStudio find the solution for you!

Comment: Thanks, I'll have him try that.

Comment: Let us know how it worked! (And what code it generated.)

Comment: It worked, he could load the text file. What do you mean with what code it generated? What code generated the error? All of the lines I posted above produced this error and since he now used the RStudio GUI to import his file, there is no code that actually worked. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Oh, when I use the RStudio load it writes some code for me and then executes it. (Then, I copy that code into my script and don't use the Import Dataset function for the rest of the project.) Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this issue is by putting double backslashes in the file path.

Eg. the following are all equivalent.

```
results = read.csv(file = '\\User\\desktop\\file.csv')
results = read.csv('\\User\\desktop\\file.csv')
results = read.csv('C:\\User\\desktop\\file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem these days.
First I have investigated my sources without succes.
The solution was deeper level.
There was a file named .Rprofile and a parameter in it that contained mixed kind slashes.

```
# LanguageServer Setup Start (do not change this chunk)
# to remove this, run languageserversetup::remove_from_rprofile
if (requireNamespace('languageserversetup', quietly = TRUE)) {
  options(langserver_library = 'C:\Users\feren\OneDrive\Dokumentumok/languageserver-library')
  languageserversetup::languageserver_startup()
  unloadNamespace('languageserversetup')
}
# LanguageServer Setup End
```

The LanguageServer came with an R related extension of Visual Code.
The problem occured when I used an "R step" in Power Query (Power BI).